# PHP Google Calendar API v2.6 - updateEvent() function

Tags: php, events, google-api, google-calendar-api

I found simple PHP class for Google Calendar API (v2.6).

https://github.com/montania/Google-Calendar-API-PHP-Class

And there is function **updateEvent**($handle, $id, $etag, $json) {...}

```
/**
* Method to update an event in the calendar. 
  If $etag is submitted it won't update your event if it has been updated since 
  you last retreived it
* @param string $handle    E-mail or handle to identify the calendar
* @param string $id        The id of the event
* @param string $etag      The e-tag of the event (optional)
* @param string $json      The complete json code from the event that you've 
                           retrieved with the changes that you want
* @return bool|object      Returns false on failure and object on success
*/
```

What I should put into to **$json** parameter ?
Can someone give me code example ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $json parameter should include the JSON formatted edited event, from the response you got when you retrieved the calendar event.

This is the steps you need to take to be able to update an event

1. Get the current event from the calendar using the getEvents() or getEvent() method.
2. Update the returned object's properties to reflect the changes you want to do to the event
3. Encode the object in JSON format using json_encode() and pass it back to the updateEvent() method

The Google Calendar API documentation explains this as well: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UpdatingEvents

Comment: I understand those 3 steps and what JSON have to contain, but I don't know how write changes and them encode them to JSON. Simplyfied ... give me example of code before $json = json_encode($string); Example: I want update name and place of event.